# In a full calendar, I want to display different data in events in different view

Tags: php, fullcalendar

Like in month I just want to display image and in week view and day view I want to display full description of events. I have done with month view, I have different data but dont have an idea how to call event data in that view. I tried with viewDisplay but dont have an idea how to call my events over here.

```
events: function(start, end, callback) {

    var currentview = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView'); //alert('event called');

    if(currentview.name == 'month')
    {
        var events = <?php echo "[".$json."]"; ?> // this is where we call the php variable
    }
    else
    {
        var events = <?php  echo "[".$weekjson."]"; ?>
    }

    callback(events);
}
```

this code is perfect but its not calling every time when my view changes.

Comment: `this code is perfect but...` lol so its not perfect :P

Answer (score 0):

I got solution that how to call event again in different view.

In viewDisplay I called function for refetchEvents, its used to recall events.

viewDisplay: function(view) {

```
     refreshEvents(view);
 },
```

function refreshEvents(view)
{

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

}